# Complicated URL Rewrite for products that includes string manipulation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking to rewrite approximately 5000 old product urls and I'm thinking that a rewrite rule in my .haccess file might do the trick, although creating this is too advanced for me.

**Old Url Example:**
Please keep in mind that the "68p4963" is randomly generated.

```
http://www.example.com/store/pc/Strapless-Monarch-Butterfly-Fairy-Wings-68p4963.htm
```

**Preferred Url example:**
This should now have a 301 redirect without the "www." and with the product name converted to lowercase.

```
http://example.com/products/strapless-monarch-butterfly-fairy-wings
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this always in */store/pc/* ?

Comment: Do you have access to Apache server config?

Comment: @JustinIurman - Yes it is always in /store/pc/ and yes I do have access to Apache Config.